# kubernetes pod disruption budget audit with Python client

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am tasked with writing a Python client app (validating admissions webhook) to determine:

1. which of these resources have PDBs configured
   ["deployments", "replicasets", "statefulsets", "horizontalpodautoscalers"]
   and
2. if they have PDB configured, verify that the PDB allows for at least one disruption ("ALLOWED DISRUPTIONS").

For the first requirement, how can I use the Python Kubernetes API to determine if the incoming request (CREATE or UPDATE) is referring to a resource that has a pdb?

The requirement is not that every CREATE/UPDATE operation has a pdb configured, but rather "if" the resource has a pbd, the request must result in the pdb having "at least one" disruption permittted.

So am I right that I must first put the incoming request thru some sort of filter that determines if the resource in question has a pdb? And if so, how can I get that filter coded?

What would psuedo-code even look like for this?
These are my first thoughts:

- list all pdbs in the cluster
- determine if the incoming request is referecing a resource that has a pdb
- if the request is referencing a resource that has a pdb, determine whether or not the request would take the pdb down to "0" disruptions
- if "yes" to previous step, do not allow the operation

This is what I have so far

```
from kubernetes import config, client
config.load_incluster_config()
app_client = client.AppsV1Api()
```

Comment: first of all, I don't think you will work with replicaset, and PDB has nothing with HPA, so I think you need to stick with Deployments and StatefulSets.

secondly, I think that it is wrong to listen to CREATE event because when you are creating a new deployment, there is no pod available yet, therefore, the PDB that is connected to the new deployment will always have a '0' disturb budget.

Comment: thank you for those inputs, I find them very useful, esp the part about pdb not having much influence on hpa.